# How to use Zorba with C++

Tags: c++, xquery, zorba

I am trying to use Zorba XQuery parser with C++ for my project. I have downloaded and installed Zorba, but I can't seem to find a way to use it in my C++ programs. The documentation doesn't say a word. So if anyone here is good with it, can you please provide me your two cents?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can find examples at [their Website](http://zorbawebsite2.my28msec.com/html/documentation/2.8.0/cxx/examples)
The general way to use an external library is to include its headers into your sourcefiles and add include its library in your link-step.

Comment: Thank you. The problem is, their header files are inside a folder called "zorba". Inside the folder, each header file says "#include <zorba/config.h>" and includes more files like this one. They're already inside the folder, so why does it say <zorba/config.h> instead of just <config.h>?

Comment: This is to make it possible to use the Zorba-headers in any possible project layout. All the zorba-user needs to make sure is that the directory containing the zorba-directory is in the include-file-path. You do NOT need to include the "zorba-directory", just ehe directory containing that. Some sort of 'include' or 'externals' dir.